# Ending Parantheses in Awk

Tags: math, awk, sed, increment

I have the following line of code, which I would desire the three below to increase by four.

```
while(i <= 3)
```

I have the following, but it's giving me an error about a closing parentheses:

```
awk '/ while(i <= /  {sub($3+0,$3+4,$3)} )  1' file >file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

Any thoughts/ideas on how to fix the error and have it increase by four?

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will +4 the value:

```
$ awk '/while\(i <= /  {sub($3+0,$3+4,$3)}  1' file
while(i <= 7)
```

Note you were matching `" while..."`, with a leading space, and you also had a `)` somewhere after `{sub()}`. Removing them and escaping the `(` solved the issue. Graphically:

```
awk '/ while(i <= /  {sub($3+0,$3+4,$3)} )  1' file
      ^     ^                            ^
   extra?   escape!                      removed!
```

In general, try to go from simple to complicated. Your basic structure is:

```
awk '/pattern/ {sub($3+0,$3+4,$3)} 1' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and telling me what I did incorrectly.

Comment: No problem : ) I added some graphic there to make it more visual